# How can i find an event by location or venue.id/name

Tags: facebook, events, location

Im doing this query to get all events from a user. This works fine.

```
SELECT name, pic, start_time, end_time, location, description 
FROM event WHERE
  eid IN ( SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = '252874629056' ) 
LIMIT 200
```

But i am having a problem with this query when a facebook page/user is the venue/location of an event. If a page/user is the venue/location it isnt a event member.

Due to the reason that i cant search by event or venue.id i have no idea how to find an event by location or venue id.

How can I?